# Modifying Viper06 circuit to get 5 V 300 mA

Tags: power-supply, buck

I got [this evaluation board](https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/STEVAL-ISA114V1/497-14146-ND/4503649) for testing [(datasheet here)](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/data_brief/04/79/a8/a5/df/2e/45/58/DM00091218.pdf/files/DM00091218.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00091218.pdf):

[image]

Ratings:

Vout = 5 V

Iout = 160 mA

It uses Viper06 IC at 30 kHz switching frequency [(datasheet here)](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/35/60/89/e4/41/69/4c/ca/DM00048250.pdf/files/DM00048250.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00048250.pdf).
I tried drawing 200 mA from it and the IC went into drain current limit mode. It was shutting down and restarting after 1 second.

Datasheet has these specs for drain current ratings:

[image: datasheet pic]

There is a way to limit the max drain current. By default, the limit is set to max. (which is what I need)

The max limit is not high enough for my use case. I need 5 V 300 mA. Is it even possible with this IC (in non-isolated buck converter mode)? What's the smallest change I should do in the board circuit to increase the current to 300 mA?

Here are things I have tried:

Board comes with 680 uH inductor. It fails (goes into overload mode) at 200 mA.

I replaced the inductor with 1 mH 500 mA inductor. It passed at 200 mA and failed at 250 mA.

1.5 mH 430 mA passed at 250 mA and failed at 300 mA.

Increasing inductor appears to be one way of increasing the output current but I am not sure whether this is the most effective way.

Comment: Not possible due to peak current limitation. Choose another switcher.

Comment: C8 looks badly soldered.